# Laravel 5 : get route parameter in Controller 's constructor

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I defined routes for a controller this way :

```
/model/{id}/view
/model/something/{id}/edit
```

I need to get the id parameter in the contructor of this controller. For example :

```
class ArtController extends Controller {

  public function __construct(Request $request){
    //dd($this->route('id'));  //Doesn't work
    //dd($request->segments()[1]); //this works for the first route but not the second
  }
}
```

How can you get the parameter `id` in the constructor of a Controller in Laravel?

Comment: Shouldn't `$this->route('id')` be `$request->route('id')`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this

```
$id = Route::current()->getParameter('id');
```

**Update:**

Starting in laravel 5.4 `getParameter` was renamed to `parameter`

```
$id = Route::current()->parameter('id');
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing the direction. I ended up using Route::input('id') because it's shorter.

Comment: but adding this to constructor breaks down the `artisan route:list` command!

Comment: Since laravel 5.4 `getParameter('name')` changed to `parameter(names)`

Answer (score 18):

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
{
    $id = $request->route('id');   

    dump($id);
}
```

Comment: This is the right answer!!  Working from 5.5 didn't check on older versions.

Answer (score 8):

You can call anywhere:

```
request()->route('id');
```

*No need for injection*

Answer (score 0):

not use segments 
use segment

```
public function __construct(Request $request){
dd($request->segment(1));}
```